# How to load Multi-texture .obj file in GLES in android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, texture-mapping, render-to-texture, multitexturing

i have to 3d obj files in android. i have searched and find many forums and now im able to load obj+mtl files successfully. but i got problem with that obj and mtl files having many texture files . in may case ,in mtl every face it has a texture (.png). how to load this type of obj files in GLES?
is it possible to load multi-texture obj in android opegl Gles?
i have min3d, 3dmodelviewer and arjpct libs but no use. please help if it is possile to load multi-texture obj in GLES

for multi_texture i have done like this

```
 mTextureHandle = setTexture(obj, textureId,GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
        ByteArrayInputStream textureIs0 = new ByteArrayInputStream(obj.getTextureData().get(0));
        int textureId0 = GLUtil.loadTexture(textureIs0);
        mTextureHandle = setTexture(obj, textureId0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        ByteArrayInputStream textureIs2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(obj.getTextureData().get(2));
        int textureId2 = GLUtil.loadTexture(textureIs2);
        mTextureHandle = setTexture(obj, textureId2, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2);
        ByteArrayInputStream textureIs3 = new ByteArrayInputStream(obj.getTextureData().get(3));
        int textureId3 = GLUtil.loadTexture(textureIs3);
        mTextureHandle = setTexture(obj, textureId3, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE3);
        ByteArrayInputStream textureIs4 = new ByteArrayInputStream(obj.getTextureData().get(4));
        int textureId4 = GLUtil.loadTexture(textureIs4);
        mTextureHandle = setTexture(obj, textureId2, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE4);
        ByteArrayInputStream textureIs5 = new ByteArrayInputStream(obj.getTextureData().get(5));
        int textureId5 = GLUtil.loadTexture(textureIs5);
        mTextureHandle = setTexture(obj, textureId5, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE5);
        ByteArrayInputStream textureIs6 = new ByteArrayInputStream(obj.getTextureData().get(6));
        int textureId6 = GLUtil.loadTexture(textureIs6);
        mTextureHandle = setTexture(obj, textureId6, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE6);
        ByteArrayInputStream textureIs7 = new ByteArrayInputStream(obj.getTextureData().get(7));
        int textureId7 = GLUtil.loadTexture(textureIs7);
        mTextureHandle = setTexture(obj, textureId7, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE7);
        ByteArrayInputStream textureIs8 = new ByteArrayInputStream(obj.getTextureData().get(8));
        int textureId8 = GLUtil.loadTexture(textureIs8);
        mTextureHandle = setTexture(obj, textureId8, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE8);
        ByteArrayInputStream textureIs9 = new ByteArrayInputStream(obj.getTextureData().get(9));
        int textureId9 = GLUtil.loadTexture(textureIs9);
        mTextureHandle = setTexture(obj, textureId9, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE9);
```

```java
public static int loadTexture(final InputStream is) {
        Log.v("GLUtil", "Loading texture from stream...");

        final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);
        GLUtil.checkGlError("glGenTextures");
        if (textureHandle[0] == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
        }

        Log.v("GLUtil", "Handler: " + textureHandle[0]);

        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        // By default, Android applies pre-scaling to bitmaps depending on the resolution of your device and which
        // resource folder you placed the image in. We don’t want Android to scale our bitmap at all, so to be sure,
        // we set inScaled to false.
        options.inScaled = false;

        // Read in the resource
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
        if (bitmap == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("couldnt load bitmap");
        }

        // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);
        GLUtil.checkGlError("glBindTexture");
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        GLUtil.checkGlError("texImage2D");
        bitmap.recycle();
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

        Log.v("GLUtil", "Loaded texture ok");
        return textureHandle[0];
    }
```